# MySQL architecture for different word clouds

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to create a word cloud on my website based on the keywords people search.

I have one free text input field where something can be entered.
I have 3 different user types on my website (anonymous, users, organizations). And I want to keep create a wordcloud on the most searched keywords for all these 3 types separately.

I was wondering what is the best architecture for MySQL to accomodate this problem.

Is it better to save all user types in 1 table and keep a "user_type" field? Or is it better to create a different table for each user type (for performance reasons?)?

As well, longer term-wise, I would like to use the user's searching history to provide better results for him. So to avoid rework later, I think it's good that I already have it linked to a specific user_id already right now.

Can anyone suggest me a mysql architecture for this issue?
I am thinking of going the way as suggested by user @Derek Downey in this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13738/how-to-design-a-schema-to-store-search-keywords). With adding a user_id in the DateofSearchTerm table.

Comment: Is there one "anonymous", many users, and many organizations?

Comment: @RickJames yes exactly true!

Comment: Do you need only clouds for each user?  Or do you also need a cloud that includes everyone's words?  Or both?  (It is hard to design a schema without knowing what the queries will be.)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want to create word clouds for both as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE words (
    user_type ENUM('anonymous', 'users', 'organizations') NOT NULL,
    group_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    word VARCHAR(...) NOT NULL,
    ct MEDIUM INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- how often user used the word
    PRIMARY KEY(user_type, user_id, word)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This will let you build an overall cloud, or a cloud for an individual user/organization.

```
SELECT word, SUM(ct) FROM words;  -- overall

SELECT word, ct
    FROM words
    WHERE user_type = 'organization'
      AND group_id = 123   -- for a particular user
```

You have not really mentioned a requirement any date.